# Simple Modal while processing data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I want to use [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to present a div while my rails app is processing some data on create. I want the page to then disappear when the show page should load. Right now, I'm presenting the modal view on clicking submit, but it seems to freeze after that. Any suggestions on how to show an activity indicator while processing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'freeze' does that mean you're not getting a response from your XHR request?

Whether you're using a homebrew xhr setup or something like jquery you should be able to detect success/failure and handle your modal status accordingly.

Side Note: This is handy utility for adding a nice spinner animation to your modal http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/.

Comment: When I say freeze - I mean that I'm not seeing the post request show up in my server log. Spin.js looks very cool. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to just have a hidden div at the bottom of my html doc and then use jquery to make it visible when someone submits the form.